# Interested in learning more about Islam -- is there a podcast that goes over the history, basic principles, etc?

Tags: practical-islam, internet

I know that this community is meant for those more well versed in Islam, but I have sincere desires to know more about the history of Islam and about the basic precepts. And truth be told, I actually purchased the "Islam for Dummies" and "Qur'an for Dummies" books because I find that I am having a lot of difficulty understanding a lot of reading material because I don't know a lot of terms because I don't have a background in Arabic. I'm embarrassed about that. Eeeek.

I was wondering if there are good tutorial websites or Podcasts out there for those just starting to learn about Islam? I can't seem to get all the **Caliphs', Companions', exegetes', etc. names** down right. I also can't keep track of the **important battles, or know why they are important**. Or what **types of groups of Islam are out there, and what the differences are?** And what the **key beliefs of Islam are (in their Arabic term)** are exactly? Or what the **most cited chapters in the Qur'an are**?

**Is there a tutorial website you could recommend or a podcast? OR even a timeline of events? Or a "who's who" in Islam" Or a list of Quranic/Arabic terms?**

I just want to make sure that I have a handy-guide as I embark on my pathway to discovering Islam.

Comment: This community is for all people like you, who want to know about islam, they have unanswered questions about islam. And don't hasitate to post any confusions on this forum. May allah guide you

Comment: And about your question, these all things come with time, you don't need to remember all the history of islam, but it will be better to know about it. What really matters is your beliefs and your understanding of the message of islam, and quran. Learning history and all these mentioned details is great, but  its not the most important thing. And i hope above suggestions by fellow members might help you.

Comment: There are mooc's on EDX that starts regularly https://www.edx.org/course/legacy-islamic-civilization-bax-bax2 https://www.edx.org/course/islam-through-its-scriptures-harvardx-hds-3221-4x I've partly taken the last it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn about Islam is by reading the Qur'an. It's a big book, so if you don't have that much time then you may open up random pages from it and read them. If you like these random texts and want to know more then read more. It claims to be the word of the Almighty God. Put it to the test. It says it's a guidence for mankind. Let it prove itself.

Also, it also says it won't guide any wrong doers. I suggest you take a bath and restrain from lying and things that are consided morally bad (just a suggestion, I am not telling you to change your way of life).

Additionally, The following links will give you an idea of the fundamental beliefs of Islam:

1. [Book of revelation](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/1)
2. [Book of Belief](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/2)

Answer (score 1):

Certainly I strongly advise you in the following:

http://bayyinah.com/ - it is an institute by Nouman Ali Khan, one of the great and young scholars. I learned so much by watching lots of his lectures on youtube.

also search for Mufti Menk too on youtube

The Bayyinah institute is something I highly recommend to you which has courses for you to learn at your own pace along with full support and help from the people too!

Comment: Nouman Ali Khan Is not a scholar, this is something he brings up every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

There's a web resource [Halal Tube](https://www.halaltube.com/) which contains YouTube videos from respectable speakers:

[image]